# How to get the second SELECT from my STORED PROCEDURE?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm calling my STORED PROCEDURE from php but this SP has 2 SELECTS, and when I recieve the array in php, I only see the result of the first SELECT...

How can I get the array from the second SELECT? I read that something like a next_result function or something like that.. but I didn't found anything that works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use function mysql_next_result(). Use something like below:

```
  do{
       while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
           // display record ...
       }
  }while( mysql_next_result($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions :

- call the SP twice from php, with a parameter in the SP that choose the right select to return (with IF THEN ELSE condition), then join your arrays in php.
- Make an UNION ALL in your SP to return the two selects at the same time.

Hope it helps !